# Plasma Device Notifier thinks all my internal hard drive partitions are removable and always shows them

Tags: kde, opensuse

Since a few weeks ago, Plasma Device Notifier thinks all my internal hard drive partitions are removable and always shows them. If I go into it's settings and select to show "Non-removable devices only", it doesn't show any devices. Selecting "All devices" or "Removable devices only" shows all devices. I didn't change my fstab settings. How can I make Device Notifier know that my internal HD partitions shouldn't be considered "removable"?

Comment: Maybe a kernel problem... Which version are you running on ? See : https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/48069

Comment: Opensuse Tumbleweed, kernel version 4.4.0-3. And this problem depends on hardware. Desktop with Intel i5-2500 and chipset Z68 has this problem. Ok, probably, this is bug. Thanks for link.